# django ImportError: cannot import name list_route

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to add a new endpoint by marking it with @list_route but when i try to import if :

```
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route
```

It cant find it. Do i need to install something for this to work (I'm new to django)?

Comment: The import as shown is correct. Have you installed djangorestframework and added it to INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: If you are using venv then keep in mind to activate it

Comment: @MarkGalloway Yes I have but it cant find that decorator

Comment: Sometimes Import Error are raised when there is an error in your view, could you post your entire traceback please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list_route` decorator is present in version 3.1.3.
See: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3.1.3/rest_framework/decorators.py

Follow the instructions on https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework to install Django REST Framework properly.

To install version 3.1.3, run: `pip install djangorestframework==3.1.3`

Answer (score 10):

When upgrading to higher versions, you might hit this question again.
`list_route` has been deprecated in favor of `@action(detail=False)`

More info in the [release 3.8 announcement](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/#deprecations)